# Grid search and cross-validation

Tags: data-science, logistic-regression, cross-validation

`X` and `y` are observations and target correspodingly.

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
parameters_logreg = {'C': [0.1, 1, 0.5], 'max_iter': [100, 102] }
gs_logreg = GridSearchCV(logreg, parameters_logreg, cv = 5)
gs_logreg.fit(X, y)
cv_logreg = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=9)
cross_val_score(gs_logreg, X, y, cv=cv_logreg, scoring='roc_auc')
```

I am doing a classification problem using logistic regression. Applying grid search I find the best hyperparamenters. After that I calculate scores on cross validation folds.

My first question is will  `gs_logreg.fit(X, y)`  effect the final scores on cross validation? How cross_val_scores works? It fits `gs_logreg` ones more but now on cv folds? Can it remember `y` after first fiting `gs_logreg.fit(X, y)`  ?

The second question is this code correct? I surprisingly got high scores for my stupid model.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Are you using any packages?

Comment: For the second question it would also be relevant what dataset you are fitting.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, why not comment out that statement (`gs_logreg.fit(X, y)`), rerun and check if the cross validation results have changed? If they do change, then that statement affects the final scores, otherwise it does not.

Comment: Already done. It didn't effect. I read the documentation and now I understand that it's  completely erases the previous fit after starting new fit.